# Thymeleaf fragment content does not replacing the main content?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use fragment of Thymeleaf. I already created the header and footer and it works well, but the content does not replacing.

How could I do this ?

**Main Layout**

```
<!-- the main layout -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vendas</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:replace="home/header :: header"> This header content is going to be replaced.</div>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <div class="container">
          <div layout:fragment="content">        
            <h1>Static content for prototyping purposes only</h1>    
          </div>      
        </div>

        <footer th:replace="home/footer :: footer" class="footer">
            This content will remain, but other content will be inserted after it.
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Customer to replace main**

```
<!-- customer -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html layout:decorate="~{home/layout}">

    <head>
        <title>Customers</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link th:href="@{/css/core.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div layout:fragment="content">
            <h1>Add a new customer</h1>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your project depend on [`thymeleaf-layout-dialect`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect)?

Comment: @caco3 I think so, but I'm using STS(spring boot) and I already read that its works automatically, in other words, all configurations came by default